# AS3: Sound.play() stops animation, why?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a working Flash movie, using a couple of AS3 scripts. The main stage has some animation going on. My player.as plays some mp3 clips when I click a button. The problem is, the stage animation stops as soon as the sound starts ie. Sound.play() starts, then animation starts again when the sound ends.

The animation is based on

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop3D);
```

so I gather something happens to ENTER_FRAME due to Sound.play(). What is weird is everything works perfectly on the Flash Test movie (ctrl+Enter). The animation does NOT stop during sound. What to do to make sure the animation goes on always?

Comment: Is there any more code we can look at?

Comment: I don't know what is relevant to paste here.. What I do notice is that if I simply comment out 1: mysound.play(pos) or 2: sndarray[current].play(), which are what happens if buttons 1 or 2 are pressed, that completely removes the problem. Then I can still enjoy the animation on a live website after pressing the buttons. But of course then no sound at all. So I've pinned it down to .play(). The animation is a .computeSpectrum thing, 3D reacting to sound. Note that it does work perfectly when offline, on Test movie.

Comment: I could now debug it further: If I play a sound on the same .as where the .computeSpectrum is, animation works even online. So it was not a problem with animation stopping, it is a problem where the sound ByteArray from another .as doesn't pass on properly (strange that there is a difference whether doing Test movie or online). So, this `bytes = new ByteArray();` is where it probably goes wrong. That works if the `Sound.play();` is on same script, but how to get that working if the sound is coming from another .as?

Comment: There might be some sort of security problem where the other .as is not accepted by `SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(bytes, true, 4);` so the animation just when sound is played by another .as file. One solution would be to combine all my .as to the main class, but that's a huge job for me and sounds very stupid. I just want to computeSpectrum in one .swf, all sound is produced in one and same .swf! How to pass (or mix) audio bytes between classes?

Comment: Found out that it also stops in Firefox if I open a YouTube video in another tab at the same time. This I pinpointed as a bug. However, I would really like to get this working even with the Firefox YouTube problem. Surely somebody has done a spectrum analyzer with a separate .as class playing the sound?

Answer (score 1):

There is no inherent problem with playing sound and animation at the same time, nor is there one with combining a (however large) number of class files - you have another problem.  There must be an error causing the Flash player to suspend execution of ActionScripts, and it is most probably one of these:

1. A [security sandbox violation](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Detecting_Security_Sandbox_Violation-16412.html).
2. An [IO error](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/errors/IOError.html) or a problem related to playing stuff that has not yet completed loading.
3. A problem related to [loading classes from a separate SWF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634757/as3-instantiate-class-from-external-swf).
4. Some other problem causing a [null pointer exception](http://curtismorley.com/2007/08/15/flash-cs3-flex-error-1009-cannot-access-a-property-or-method-of-a-null-object-reference/).

To debug this, first check your flashlog.txt.  If you don't have one, [set up the Flash content debugger plugin](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=logging_04.html). See what error codes are thrown, go on from there.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me a lot. I found out two things, it was indeed a security sandbox problem. Annoyingly, the problem actually wasn't there when accessing www.mysite.com. I had been debugging on mysite.com, without the www prefix. The security problem exists only if www is left out. I tried all sorts of things but could not find the answer for this new problem. How to allow full sandbox permissions for the same website without www prefix?

Comment: Allow access from *.mysite.com

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like to do. How? At least `Security.allowDomain("*");` doesn't work.

Comment: Set up a crossdomain.xml.  Also, the HTML you embed the swf in might need allowScriptAccess="always". Check this: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403183.html

Comment: Thank you again. I'd be delighted to also get an example for the crossdomain.xml, but of course I can try to figure it out myself too. I found several examples but they radically differed from each other, I do not know which one is proper for this simple purpose. Also I don't know where to put the file and what to add to the document class though I tried a couple of things.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213251/can-someone-post-a-well-formed-crossdomain-xml-sample